# How do I get Avalon Drake egg in Puzzle & Dragons Z?

Tags: puzzle-and-dragons

I play Puzzle & Dragons Z, the one on the part-mario cartridge, and i was wondering how do I get avalon drake egg? It is the final boss of postgame.

I do know that if you make a combo of 10+ at once you can get rare goodies, i know because i got a Divinegon Chip and evolved my Annow because of it

But Avalon doesn't drop eggs, does it??